# Trying to get iframe parent window element's data, and append to body of iframe

Tags: iframe, parent, output

I have a hidden element on my [parent] page:

```
<div class=output-data style="display:none">
    <h1>Testing!</h1>
</div>
```

And now, I'm trying to get an iFrame embeded on the page to find the `.output-data` div, assign it's contents to a var, and then append it to itself *as* the document. So my iFrame markup is literally just this:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>

    var outputData;
    (function($){

        outputData = $(window.parent.document).find('div.output-data').html();
        $(document.body).append(outputData);

})(this.jQuery);

</script>
```

In other words, I'm trying to get my iFrame to assume and display the HTML contents of the `.output-data` div, but it's not working and I can't seem to figure out why? I can't find anything in my web inspector? Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a JS method (GetData) in the parent that returns the content you want.
You can call this method from the iframe through the window.parent property.

```
function GetData(){
  return $(".output-data").html();
}

Ex: from the iframe: var content = window.parent.GetData()
```

Comment: I'm getting `Object [object global] has no method 'callOutput'` in my parent window?

Comment: Are you calling the method from inside the iframe? It has to be defined in the parent, but called from the iframe

Comment: Yup. Here's what I've done (It's a bit so I jsFiddle'd it all): http://jsfiddle.net/T6dNH/ - I can't see where I've gone wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector context argument:

```
$('div.output-data',window.parent.document).html();
```